# How to flag records in a data set between, but not including, two chosen rows?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
 Category                 Amount

 SALES  
 Alcohol Sales            $33,436 
 Cigarette Sales          78,953 
 TOTAL SALES              645,860 
 Alcohol COS              22,313 
 Cigarette COS            59,098 
 Grocery CC Fees          1,956 
 Roller Grill Spoilage    432 
 TOTAL COST OF SALES      55,555
```

I want to add a flag to everything between "TOTAL SALES and "TOTAL COST OF SLAES" so the output would be something like this:

```
  Category               Amount       Flag

 SALES                            
 Alcohol Sales           $33,436 
 Cigarette Sales         78,953 
 TOTAL SALES             645,860       
 Alcohol COS             22,313       1
 Cigarette COS           59,098       1
 Grocery CC Fees         1,956        1
 Roller Grill Spoilage   432          1
 TOTAL COST OF SALES     55,555
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new variable `flag` that retains its value across observations, and set/unset it at the appropriate times.  Something like:

```
data sales2;
  set sales;
  length flag $1;
  retain flag ' ';
  if category = 'TOTAL COST OF SALES' then
    flag = ' ';
  output;
  if category = 'TOTAL SALES' then
    flag = '1';
run;
```

Comment: The key here is the use of the RETAIN statement. Otherwise flag would reset with each row. Examples: http://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2011/CC/PharmaSUG-2011-CC15.pdf